# Nexus 7 ADB with Google driver MTP issue on Win7?

Tags: nexus-7

when connected with ADB Google driver my N7 doesn't show in Porable devices and I can't access my files. If I uninstall ADB driver (with delete drivers flag checked) win7 does reinstall of its own drivers and It work.

I would like to use my N7 for development but also would like to transfer my files, is there any workaround, and has anyone else come across same issue?

Thanks for helping out.

Comment: My answer has helped you?
If - yes, please confirm the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

> 1. Download USB driver -  Nexus 7 USB driver for Windows ([Link](http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207&p=28&s=2))
> 2. Run Device Manager
> 3. reconnect the Nexus tablet -> Select Android Phone (or other name you device)
> 4. Click right mouse button -> update
> 5. Select you download driver
> 6. Install

In consol Windows -> adb devices

Answer:

List of devices attached

xxxxx   device

transfer files:

The "adb push  " copies a file or folder from the local system to the remote emulator or device.

The "adb pull  " copies a file or folder from the remote emulator or device to the local system.

Information links:

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/0-RzE0v-G3k

http://www.herongyang.com/Android/adb-push-and-pull-Command.html

Comment: This was also helpful http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/48309/how-do-i-get-my-nexus-7-to-show-up-in-the-adb-devices-list

Comment: How do I run the device manager? Is it the same thing as the Android Virtual Device Manager, AVD?

Answer (score 0):

*USB debugging and MTP connection do not play well together.
AFAIK on most devices before Nexus 7 using the two simultaneously wasn't even an option.*

So, to avoid having ADB problems, your **best shot is to not use MTP**.
I've found that [at least for my Nexus 7 FHD] using Camera USB mode instead of MTP proves more stable, e.g. solves the infamous "unathorized" issue.

*Also, for transferring files back and forth, there are less painful options like the AirDroid app [not affiliated] -- lets you transfer stuff using your browser.*