# Why does Eclipse not recognize my Nexus 7?

Tags: android, eclipse

I just got the 4.2.2 update but now Eclipse does not recognize my Nexus 7 (used as my app development platform). I have not been able to test a single run since the update.

The Android Device Chooser box now shows Target as *Unknown and Offline*!

Comment: have enable developer mode on your deivice

Comment: Read this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11533228/not-seeing-nexus7-in-eclipses-android-devices.

Comment: What does `adb devices` say ?

Answer (score 2):

You may need to reinstall the USB drivers for your phone, and also make sure you enabled debugging mode on your phone's developer options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update your Android SDK to the latest one from the *Android SDK Manager*.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the OEM drivers for the specific phone from the manufactuers, also. That usually gets missed.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue (device shown but only offline) and tried lots of things for several hours, e.g. ...

- installing Asus driver (http://support.asus.com/Download.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=Nexus%207&p=28&s=2)
- using newsest Google ADB driver (and SDK)
- removing other ABD drivers (Samsung, ...)
- follwing steps [Nexus 7 ADB with Google driver MTP issue on Win7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13892940/nexus-7-adb-with-google-driver-mtp-issue-on-win7)
- trying to unplug/plug, restart adb, etc. as per [Why does adb return offline after the device string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8162581/why-does-adb-return-offline-after-the-device-string)
- trying MTP and PTP mode [Nexus 7 not visible over USB via "adb devices" from Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64)
- using PdaNet for driver installation as per [Nexus 7 not visible over USB via "adb devices" from Windows 7 x64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11974700/nexus-7-not-visible-over-usb-via-adb-devices-from-windows-7-x64) too

... as well as all combinations ;) sometimes it worked, sometimes it didn't (this changed often after workstation restart). It gave me a headache.

What *definitely worked* was setting up the **SDK in a Linux environment**. I created a virtual maschine, installed Ubuntu and the SDK, forwarded the USB port - et voilà - no issue.

I know, this might not be an option for you - so this is just in case of ... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons. One is installing the correct driver and setting up the development options correctly. There are lots of answers for that one. The second reason (and the one that always catches me) is that when you first obtain a new Nexus 7 tablet, it is set in 'media mode'. In order to work with adb it needs to be set in 'camera mode'. To set it to camera mode one goes in settings/Storage. Then touch that little menu at the top right. Touch 'USB computer connection' and you will be offered a choice between media mode or camera mode. If it is not 'camera mode' all the driver and developer settings one fusses with make no difference. Set it to camera mode.

Answer (score 0):

Drivers got installed successfully and still device is not recognized by DDMS? Here is what worked for me:

1. Go to device's notification bar
2. Tap on "Connected as a media device"
3. select Camera (PTP) option.

Device drivers automatically will get updated for Camera option and device will get listed in DDMS.